# validate variable contains string value

Tags: c#

I have one variable which contains string value like below:

```
var stringWithSpecialChar = "/Home%";
```

Sometimes this variable does not contain any value like below:

```
var stringWithSpecialChar = "/%";
```

I have to check here whether this variable contains string value or not.
Everytime string value is changing so it is not sure that i will get the same value another time.

Comment: Do you need to capture what's in between "/" and "%"?

Comment: What is your definition of *a valid value*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand what is a valid value in your question, so:
Use below code if a valid value is a value of some letters or some digits:

```
using System.Linq;

if (str.Any(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
{
    //Some codes
}
```

But I recommend you; for checking a valid or invalid string use `Regex` like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var regex = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]");  // You have many options here
if (regex.IsMatch(str))
{
    //Some codes
}
```

Comment: Sha, your suggestion worked for me. I am upvoting your answer. Regex is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, do a foreach loop on your variable to check if it will see a string or letter.

```
 var stringWithSpecialChar = "/Home%";
 bool blStringInput;
 blStringInput = IsThisString(stringWithSpecialChar);
```

Method to check if it will see a string value:

```
   public static bool IsThisString(string strInput)
    {
        foreach (char c in strInput)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(c))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Well that will return false if it detects a non-letter character in a string :)

Comment: Misreading your code! - With using LinQ: `blStringInput = str.Any(char.IsLetter);` ;)

Comment: That will do it as well ;) @shA.t

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple implementation of your problem. I have considered that anything in between `/` and `%` is a string [*It might contain numbers, alphabets or special characters*]. Also, I have included a check inside the function whether the string is valid or not by checking whether it starts and ends with `/` and `%` respectively.

```
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var stringWithSpecialChar = "/Home%";
    bool ans = checkIfStringIsPresent(stringWithSpecialChar);
    Console.WriteLine(ans);
    stringWithSpecialChar = "/%";
    ans = checkIfStringIsPresent(stringWithSpecialChar);
    Console.WriteLine(ans);
    stringWithSpecialChar = "/hi%";
    ans = checkIfStringIsPresent(stringWithSpecialChar);
    Console.WriteLine(ans);
    stringWithSpecialChar = "/12#%";
    ans = checkIfStringIsPresent(stringWithSpecialChar);
    Console.WriteLine(ans);
  }
  public static bool checkIfStringIsPresent(string s){
    var len = s.Length;
    if(s[0]!='/' || s[len-1]!='%')
      return false; // if string doesn't start and and with correct symbols, then return false
    var i = 0;
    for(i=1;i<len-1;i++){
      return true; // something is present in between / and %, so return true
    }
    return false; // else return false
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the special characters and know they are at the begining and end of the `string`, `Trim()` could be used:

```
var stringWithSpecialChar = "/Home%";
var value = stringWithSpecialChar.Trim('/', '%');

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    // Use value...
```

One could also use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)` in the condition depending on your needs.